# Twig: Access a parameters in url

Tags: symfony, parameters, twig

suppose I have this symfony url: http:/www.site.com/page/parameter

How can I access "parameter" in twig? I mean, the conversion of $this->getPageParams() in symfony repository.

I don't want to explode the url or similar, it's too weird.

Thanks!

Comment: you really need to read symfony documentation. This is a basic of creating a route in symfony

Comment: yes I already know, but it's not the solution: I've created a lot of routes, a very big quantities. but in this case I can't get the param.

Comment: in general, you want to retrieve the last fragment (identified by a slash) of an uri's path?

Comment: yes but in the best way for twig

Comment: why don't you pass it by the controller ? which is made for the logic

Comment: maybe 'cause I need it in twig

Comment: you need it twig ok, but you can pass it to your twig by the controller ...

Comment: After having done some searches. I don't find a solution without spliting or slicing the url.(In your question you said you don't want to split/explode the string)

Comment: I think I must surrender... ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access to the last element of the pathInfo, you could simply do the following:

```
{{ app.request.pathInfo|split('/')|last }}
```

See [this](https://twigfiddle.com/kijbdc) working example

Comment: hi @Zak you are welcome. You can wrap in a macro or write your own function for it